# How does node.js clusters, redis, single thread and non blocking i/o works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I will try to sum up all of what I have recently learned about node configuration. If it is correct please confirm. If I messed this up please correct me and others.

Node.js is a server.
As a server it can receive requests from clients.
Lets say that there 200 requests in period of time.

Since node.js is a single thread it can handle all of those requests by one unit / with one core.

However node is also event non blocking i/o, which means that someone can requests some method in the node.js API that takes 1 minute to complete while other can requests another method which also takes 1 minute to complete. Both can be handled simustanly without the need of wait for each other to complete.

Now that sounds awesome but it can even be better if we assist the node server and let it work as a proxy spreading those tasks of the 200 requests to clusters/workers. Therefore the node server becomes a proxy between clients to workers. Like a project manager :)

The benefit of this, is that instead of one core processing 200 requests we now have 4 cores processing those requests and each of core is event non blocking i/o (depending on the server specifications ofcourse) .

Thats super fast probably. Isnt it?

And here is the problem / what I want to understand:

**How to make those clusters/workers work as a shared?**

I mean, if 50 requests transferred to core 1 and 50 requests transferred to core 2 and so for and so on until all of the available cores,
how can I send a socket emit to both different cores? (`socket.io`)

How can clusters run together with a rate limiter? I mean, rate limiter will ban a user who tries to spam or something, but then immediately revoke the ban of this user since it goes to a different cluster.

I have heard that the `Redis` suppose to give an help with this.
But its very confusing, redis is a DB isnt it? 
I am working with MongoDB so why I need more DB?

I will put here some code maybe the solution is just right the corner:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var redis = require("socket.io-redis");

if(cluster.isMaster) {

    var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;
    console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');

    for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' stopped with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });

    cluster.fork();

} else {

  // define main required variables
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var cors = require('cors');
  var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);
  var mongojs = require('mongojs');
  var db = mongojs("mongodb://user:pass*@ip:port/dbname", []);
  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
  var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
  var request = require('request');
  var fcm = require('./routes/fcm');
  var Excel = require('exceljs');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  var rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

  // define some global limiter against spammer
  var limiter = new rateLimit({
    windowMs: 10*60*1000, // 10 minutes
    max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs (11 is on load and more 100 later on)
    delayMs: 0, // disable delaying - full speed until the max limit is reached
    message: "Service is block for you, try again later"
  });

  //  apply to all requests
  app.use(limiter);

  // allow cross origin to access my api
  app.use(cors());

  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

  // my own routes
  require('./routes/sockets')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
  require('./routes/userServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, rateLimit);
  require('./routes/ridesServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
  require('./routes/offersServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, rateLimit);
  require('./routes/notificationsServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
  require('./routes/scopeServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
  require('./routes/excelServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, Excel, fs, path);

  // listen
  server.listen("8080", function() {
    console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");
  });

}
```

How to handle those things?

Thanks.

Comment: Redis in this case just helps you to maintain a state that is shared between the cluster nodes, theoretically you can also use mongodb for that, but redis might prove to scale better for this particular task, and a lot of cluster management tools already support it out of the box. For the socket emit, do you really need to send it to both cores? since you dont want the emit action to trigger the action twice I guess, it will be sufficient if it arrives at one of the cores?

Comment: I dont know if I need to send it to all of the cores, I just need to set this working and set to all the necessary listeners, for example: a new post inserted, I need to emit this to all who views the board.
But as I understand there 50 users in core 1 and 50 users in core 2.
Those who in core 1 do not listen to core 2, am I wrong?

Comment: Could you please show an example based on my code, sending emit one time to all listeners and maintain rate limit properly?

Comment: Ah I understand it more clearly now. In this case it makes sense to add redis because you can use PUB/SUB to propagate your events to the cores. Unfortunately I dont have the resources right now to provide a complete example, but https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#publish--subscribe should be able to help you

Comment: @QiongWu please check my answer, I have found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have found the solution and here it is:**

For socket.io with multiple clusters do this:

**Step 1:** Install Redis on your machine: `brew install redis`

**Step 2:** Run the Redis server: `redis-server` (from a new tab in the SHELL).

**Step 3:** Install the Redis dependency: `npm install redis --save`

**Step 4:** Include the Redis adapter after the definition of the `io` like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

You are ready to go.

For a rate limiter using Redis please follow the next [NPM Repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-limiter)

Comment: Thanks for sharing!